# mysql-python with Percona Server installation

Tags: python, percona

I'm trying to install `mysql-python` package on a machine with Centos 6.2 with Percona Server.
However I'm running into **EnvironmentError: mysql_config not found** error.

I've carefully searched information regarding this error but all I found is that one needs to add path to mysql_config binary to the PATH system variable.

But it looks like, with my percona installation, a don't have mysql_config file at all

`find / -type f -name mysql_config` returns nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_config is a part of mysql-devel package.

Comment: The answer is for Centos. Apt-get is probably Ubuntu, so it is something different.